# Компилятор для языка Пролог в ОС Linux

Tags: linux, prolog

Подскажите, какой компилятор подойдет для изучения языка. Также чтобы по работе с этим компилятором была русскоязычная документация.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первая же [ссылка](http://www.gprolog.org/#download) в гугле.

Любая русская документация к прологу подойдёт.

Answer (score 2):

Из книжек по Прологу:

- "Программирование на языке Пролог для искусственного интеллекта", Братко И.;
- "Искусство программирования на языке Пролог", Стерлинг Л.